# Can I import a csv file as metadata to a library?

Tags: import, csv

Example scenario:

I have a folder (on a file share) that contains 10 doc files.  I also have a csv file that contains, in the first column, the names of each of those files.  Proposed metadata is in each of the subsequent columns of the csv.  Is there any way to transfer this csv-doc combination to a SharePoint library?

---

Of course this wouldn't be a big problem if I actually had 10 documents in a folder, but my case would involve around 100 of these folders, and around 100 doc files in each folder.  What we have done so far is import the csv to a list and the docs to a library, add a calculated column in the list that appends the file name column to the end of the document library's URL, providing a link to the document.

(SP 2010 Standard)

Is there a better way that I'm missing?  Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 ways of doing this: Either write your own tool, or use a bought one. There is nothing out of the box I am afraid.

If you want to write your own tool, then I would look at SPServices on codeplex I believe it has just had a taxonomy update. Or use a webpart in page.

The two companies to look at, that provide tools for exactly this are [Metavis](http://www.metavistech.com/) and [Axceler](http://axceler.com/).